# Sorry, something went wrong after cancel application connexion on SDK 3.0

Tags: authentication, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using the new PHP SDK 3.0 and I use the new getLoginUrl() function with the following parameters.

```
$paramsLogin = array(
    'scope' => PERMISSIONS,
    'redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI
);
```

If the user clicks "cancel" on the application permissions popup, I redirect the user on an error page which contains a message explaining that he has to accept the permissions in order to participate to the contest and a new login button.

But when i click on the login button again, facebook displays the following message :

> Sorry, something went wrong. We're working on getting this fixed as
>   soon as we can.

If I wait for a while then click again on the login button It works as expected.

I read somewhere that facebook should be displaying "Leave application" in the permission popup instead of "Cancel" I guess this is the issue.

Anyone has any clue on how to solve that problem or should I submit a bug report on facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently open as a bug in Facebook's bug tracker, see here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/287587111265733 - I reproduced it myself earlier, and it's been assigned for fixing

I believe if you wait a while the dialog works again (i.e the failure only happens if you go back to the dialog quickly after rejecting it, which shouldn't really happen except when aggressively testing).

Comment: Yes this happens during fast testing. Thank you for your answer. I'll keep an eye on the bug tracker. 

You are right if you wait like 30 seconds it works again.